# Django - model in multiple apps (multiple tables)

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to import a model from one app into another creating a new table etc.

```
# app1/models.py

class MyModel(models.Model):
   myfield = models.CharField(...)
   ...
```

```
# app2/models/__init__.py

from app1.models import MyModel as MyShadowModel
```

*What I would expect*: `python manage.py makemigrations` would see changes in `app2` and create the according tables.

- Why does it not happen?
- What would I have to do to achieve this?

**Background**

A Django project shall process Data and make changes visible. It consists of two apps:

`app1` contains already processed data
`app2` processes changes and shall show what data in `app1` would look like.

The idea: `app2` processes the data into a "shadow" model. Therefore i would like to use the exact same model as `app1` in my models in `app2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Importing the model doesn't suffice. Imagine you only have to do some logic with MyModel in app2's models.py. It doesn't make sense to  create another table.

You have to declare another model that inherits from the parent model in order to replicate it.

`from app1.models import MyModel`

`class MyShadowModel(MyModel):`
...

Comment: perfect, thanks. could you please explain, why my aproach does not work?

Comment: Note that inheriting from a model which is not abstract is used for [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) (Simply an extra table with a one-to-one field with the parent model), hence the data saved for `MyShadowModel` would actually still be stored in `MyModel` which I assume is not what OP wants.